# How to get number of line in page qweb report. Odoo 11

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I want to add condition in report qweb (invoice report) according to number of line in page.
How can I get number of line in each page in report?

```
 <body class="container">
                <div id="wrapwrap">
                    <main>
                        <t t-raw="0"/>
                        <t t-if="counter == 10">
                            <p style="page-break-after:always;">Add some code</p>
                            <t t-set="counter" t-value="0"/>
                        </t>
                        <t t-set="counter" t-value="counter + 1"/>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some more info... number of line from what? invoice_lines? And please add some code that you might tried, in order to help you my friend.

Comment: I edited the post : I added my code , I want to add a page-break-after , after a completed page of invoice report . I want to test if the page is fulled to add some code after each page . So , I want to count number of line in one page . @southernegro

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I'm late.

You can use "line_index" in order to get what you want. This is way simpler than creating a variable on the qweb.

```
<t t-if="line_index == 4">
    <p style="page-break-after:always;"/>
</t>
```